# testflight update didnt appear in appstore

Tags: ios, app-store

ipa was loaded into test flight, tested on the device, and then pushed to the store. So, the app in store is marked as "ready for sale" with the appropriate version number. Now, when i load app directly from the store on my phone I do not see the features added in last update, although the version in store corresponds to that tested earlier in testflight. What could be the reason?

P.S. I fill in the update for the first time

Comment: TestFlight allows multiple builds of the same version. Are you sure you selected the most up to date build when submitting your app?

Comment: @BrandonStillitano im new in ios, but it seems to be ok, because the version specified in Info.plst and at store are the same. And the date of loading in test flight is the same as in the store =(

Comment: Version means nothing on TestFlight. You can have 15 of the same version all uploaded within 10 minutes of each other. What you need to check is the build number. This must be unique regardless of version and must always increment.